Demo Content instalation, multisite
Is it possible to install demo content on a site-by-site basis on a Magento multisite?
I want to configure one of my sites on a Magento multisite install to look like one of the demo content setups from the theme I'm using. If I install the demo content will it overwrite or remove any of my existing content? Is there an easy way to configure a new site to look like the demo content from a theme or do I need to do it block by block?
